# Integrating a question migrated from MO with answers here at MSE?

Tags: support, migration, cross-posting, merging

I recently asked a long soft question, involving a reference request, both here and on MO, about the traditional presentation of the change of variables formula for multiple integrals in advanced theoretical calculus texts. (I originally asked on MSE but thought I might elicit a richer discussion from MO, where pedagogical questions often get very illuminating answers. I don't really see why my question is worse than hundreds of other soft questions on MO, but I won't argue the point; I'm happy with the migration.) The MO post was eventually community wiki.

The MO question was [migrated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1598792/why-dont-standard-analysis-texts-relax-the-injectivity-requirement-of-the-multi) yesterday. FWIW, the original MSE [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1595387/dropping-injectivity-from-multivariable-change-of-variables) has been upvoted 9 times and favorited by 6 users, and it received one answer from Christian Blatter. But the MO question (14 upvotes) also got a couple of answers. I'm worried one of these posts is going to get deleted as a duplicate. I've also done some more digging in the literature and want to post an answer myself regarding the reference request.

Is it possible for a moderator to move the answers (and perhaps the reputation points from upvotes) to a single posting of the question (**preferably the MO version**, which I tweaked)? I don't want to lose Christian's input, even though I disagreed with it in the comments. Obviously several users found the question worth asking, so I think they deserve to have all the answers in one place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should flag one copy of your question for moderator's attention, explaining that it is an exact duplicate due to migration, and that you want it merged with the other copy.

Comment: Thanks!.........